# How to implement Firebase Microsoft OAuth in iOS Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, oauth, firebase-authentication

I'm fairly new to Swift and Firebase and I'm trying to get the Microsoft OAuth provider working as described here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/microsoft-oauth?authuser=0

My App is stable when run, but the MSLoginTapped button does nothing and when debugging I'm only able to see that `provider.getCredentialWith` doesn't appear to run because I do not receive my print statement.

There seemed to be multiple errors in the documentation, so I doctored it up as best possible and submitted a request for review of the documentation.

Firebase Documentation snippet:

```swift
provider.getCredentialWithUIDelegate(nil) { credential, error in
    if error != nil {
        // Handle error.
    }
    if credential != nil {
        Auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential) { authResult, error in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle error.
            }
            // User is signed in.
            // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
            // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
            // credential.accessToken
        }
    }
}
```

Problem 1:  `provider.getCredentialWithUIDelegate` is not recognized.

Problem 2:  `Auth().signInAndRetrieveData` is not recognized.

========== ========== ========== ========== ==========

Here's what I'm working with (that's NOT working):

```swift
class LoginViewController: UIViewController {

    var ref : DatabaseReference!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    @IBAction func MSLoginTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")
        provider.getCredentialWith(nil) { (credential, error) in
            if error != nil {
                // Handle error.
                print("Failed to retreive credential.")
                return
            }
            if credential != nil {
                Auth.auth().signInAndRetrieveData(with: credential!) { authResult, error in
                    if error != nil {
                        // Handle error.
                    }
                    // User is signed in.
                    // IdP data available in authResult.additionalUserInfo.profile.
                    // OAuth access token can also be retrieved:
                    // credential.accessToken
                }
            } else {
                print("Credential is nil.")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Ran into the same problem.
let provider = OAuthProvider(providerID: "microsoft.com")

**provider** is a local variable, getCredentialWith is async and ARC will get rid of **provider**. Make it global scope.

[Firebase does not show up sign page for microsoft.com in Swift / iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55399758/firebase-does-not-show-up-sign-page-for-microsoft-com-in-swift-ios)

Comment: Thank you, that worked.  I had put this objective on the back burner for a while and just got around to testing your solution.

Comment: Well, it almost worked...  I can log a user in, but I still cannot get the user ID for the logged in user.  It worked great with the drop-in email authentication screen that I always used in the past, but with OAuth the authResult always returns nil so I can't read the user email address and etc.

Comment: add below code  self.microsoftAuth = Auth.auth() and you would not get nil. you need to add as shown in below. provider?.getCredentialWith(nil ) { credential, error in
        if error != nil {
        }
if let x = credential {
self.microsoftAuth = Auth.auth()
            self. authMicrosoft?.signIn(with: x) { authResult, error in
                if error != nil {
                    // Handle error.
                }
                print(authResult?.additionalUserInfo?.profile)
            }
        } else {

        }